# Custom panel with layout engine

Tags: c#, winforms, custom-controls

I'm trying to create a custom Panel control with my own layout engine.
I need every control that is added to my panel to be added below and to take full width (-padding), like below:
[image]

Below is my code:

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Forms.Layout;

namespace VContainer
{
    internal class VerticalFillList : Panel
    {
        public VerticalFillList()
        {
            AutoScroll = true;
            MinimumSize = new Size(200, 200);
            Size = new Size(200, 300);
            Padding = new Padding(10);
        }

        private readonly VerticalFillLayout _layoutEngine = new VerticalFillLayout();

        public override LayoutEngine LayoutEngine
        {
            get { return _layoutEngine; }
        }

        private int _space = 10;

        public int Space
        {
            get { return _space; }
            set
            {
                _space = value;
                Invalidate();
            }
        }
    }

    internal class VerticalFillLayout : LayoutEngine
    {
        public override bool Layout(object container, LayoutEventArgs layoutEventArgs)
        {
            var parent = container as VerticalFillList;

            Rectangle parentDisplayRectangle = parent.DisplayRectangle;
            Point nextControlLocation = parentDisplayRectangle.Location;

            foreach (Control c in parent.Controls)
            {
                if (!c.Visible)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                c.Location = nextControlLocation;
                c.Width = parentDisplayRectangle.Width;
                nextControlLocation.Offset(0, c.Height + parent.Space);
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Above code works fine, except one thing:
when I'm adding controls to my container they are added correctly (new below parent, 100% width), but when height of controls is bigger than my container height I get horizontal scrollbars, but after adding couple controls more scrollbar is removed.
[image: adding components]

Same thing happens when I want to resize my container:
[image: resizing container]

How this can be fixed? I just need to remove that horizontal scrollbar.

Of course all improvements are welcome :)

**I don't want to use table layout or flow layout as this one gives me exactly when I need.**

I need a simple container that orders all child controls from top to bottom and stretches them horizontally so they take as much width so container horizontal scrollbar isn't needed.

Comment: but if it be fixed you can not to put news bottons forever... o_o

Comment: @MayogaX - I know that :) I just wanted to show my point. I'll have custom controls instead of buttons. My point was to show how my panel behaves. Most of time I'll have 2-3 controls in there, but when user will add new one I want to avoid situation when that horizontal scrollbar is visible. The same situation with resizing my application. I'll be holding max 5-6 controls in there. Above is just a demo to show unwanted behavior.

Comment: You are trying to solve a problem that the Winforms designers carefully side-stepped in their LayoutEngine class.  Layouts like this are *bi-stable*.  The most typical outcome of trying to address it is getting stuck in an endless loop with the horizontal scrollbar flickering on and off.  You're kinda doomed to reinvent the class and end up doing it the same way.

Comment: @HansPassant - I know I'm stuck :/ Ideally what I would like is to hide horizontal scrollbar for my panel definitely, so only vertical scrollbar would be auto, something like `hscrollbar=off;vscrollbar=auto`. I think this might solve my problem with flickering scrollbar

Comment: @HansPassant - so what do You suggest? I was trying to do the same layout with flow layout, but it wasn't what I wanted. Custom panel at first was ideal solution.

Comment: I suggest you do not do this.  Idle words, I know, it takes trying to make it work to appreciate why Winforms works the way it does and discovering that the "ideal solution" is actually a boat anchor.  I can't help you get to that conclusion faster, good luck with it.

Comment: @HansPassant - for a temporary solution in layout engine when I'm setting component size I'm subtracting 10, this seems to work, but it's a temporary solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a working example that unfortunately, does not use your Layout Engine class.  It simply relies on the OnControlAdded and OnControlRemoved methods, and anchoring and setting the AutoScrollMinSize property to specifically make sure the horizontal scrollbar never appears:

```
internal class VerticalPanel : Panel {
  private int space = 10;

  public int Space {
    get { return space; }
    set {
      space = value;
      LayoutControls();
    }
  }

  protected override void OnControlAdded(ControlEventArgs e) {
    base.OnControlAdded(e);
    LayoutControls();
  }

  protected override void OnControlRemoved(ControlEventArgs e) {
    base.OnControlRemoved(e);
    LayoutControls();
  }

  private void LayoutControls() {
    int height = space;
    foreach (Control c in base.Controls) {
      height += c.Height + space;
    }
    base.AutoScrollMinSize = new Size(0, height);

    int top = base.AutoScrollPosition.Y + space;
    int width = base.ClientSize.Width - (space * 2);
    foreach (Control c in base.Controls) {
      c.SetBounds(space, top, width, c.Height);
      c.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Right;
      top += c.Height + space;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Layout Engine was just an option that worked quite well for me, but I had problems with scrollbar. If Your solution solves that problem then it's perfect for me :)

Comment: I checked Your solution, works like a charm :) the only thing should be added is override of `OnControlRemoved` to call `LayoutControls` to remove scrollbar.

Answer (score -1):

You can set the AnchorProperty at you Buttons like:

```
button1.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Right | AnchorStyles.Top;
```

So they'll be resized horizontally

Comment: I don't need anchor for buttons, because my layout engine handles position of every component in container. Buttons inside my custom panel resize correctly. What I need to do is to remove horizontal scrollbar, because sometimes it is visible.